# Java Code to read file is not compiling on VS code editor

Tags: java, visual-studio, file

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
/*
 * PROJECT I: ReadData.java
 *
 * A sample code which demonstrates how to read data from an ASCII file using
 * the Scanner
 */


public class ReadData {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    double x,y,rad;
    int lineCount = 0;

    //Initialise the max and minimum to something sensible
    double maxX = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    double minX = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double maxY = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    double minY = Double.MAX_VALUE;
 try {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Yakov\\Desktop\\Study stuff\\MA117\\Project 1.data");
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)));

      while(scanner.hasNext()) {

        //Read the three valies on each line of the file
        x = scanner.nextDouble();
        y = scanner.nextDouble();
        rad = scanner.nextDouble();

        //Increment the linecounter. 
        lineCount++;

        // Find max, min for x and y coords
        if (x > maxX) {
          maxX = x;
        }
        if (y > maxY) {
          maxY = y;
        }
        if (x < minX) {
            minX = x;
        }
        if (y < minY) {
          minY = y;
        }

      }
    } catch(Exception e) {
      System.err.println("An error has occured. See below for details");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Information about the data:");
    System.out.println("  Number of lines in file: " + lineCount);

    System.out.format("  Max x-coord: %10.9f\n", maxX);
    System.out.format("  Min x-coord: %10.9f\n", minX);
    System.out.format("  Max y-coord: %10.9f\n", maxY);
    System.out.format("  Min y-coord: %10.9f\n", minY);

  }

}
```

I'm trying to run this Java code in VS code editor. It is a sample code which is supposed to be able to run, which is provided on the internet. How do I make this run? Is there maybe a problem in this code? The file I have inserted in is real( it exists) , so I dont see any reason this code is not running. I am using windows. Any idea how to fix this? The error is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
    at ReadData.main(ReadData (1).java:24)"
```

**Edit: import of scanner is not the problem**

Comment: Which line is line 24 in your code? A good Java development IDE should directly point you to that line.

Comment: @Robert line 13, where it states public static void main (....). i mean that's what it's saying now..

Comment: Please read my comment again. I was not asking for line 13 - I as was asking for line 24 because this is the line that can't be compiled.

Comment: @Robert yes, the line 24 is again(in the unedited version of the file with comments) is public static main (...)

Comment: The code in your question compiles without any problem.

Comment: @Robert may it be a problem with my windows? Because it's clearly not a file problem, it exists..

Comment: Oh, no the error wa obvious. The filename: The first rule of Java is THE CLASS NAME IS ALWAYS IDENTICAL TO THE FILE NAME + `.java`! Your file name is invalid: `ReadData (1).java`.

Comment: Now it is time to blame VS Code - ever other java IDE would have pointed you to that problem. Do yourself a favor and use a real Java IDE instead such as IntelliJ or Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that you have violated the "first rule of Java":

Every class have to be saved in an file with identical name appended by `.java`.

Therefore the class `ReadData` have to be saved in a file named `ReadData.java` - not `ReadData (1).java` as you did.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have an import for Scanner - it's under `java.util` and you only have `java.io.*`

Comment: i am so so sorry, it has been imported, but in the editing of this question because of my noob skills it was hidden. So i'm sorry, it's not the problem...

Comment: @user6969 then i'm not sure, because i copy/pasted into my own file your exact content and it worked - threw a FileNotFound, but that's ok. I created a test file with 2 rows, 3 doubles in each row and pointed it there and it worked fine. Do you have a JDK installed?

Comment: yes, i'm running other codes already for a month now, it should be working. Thank you anyway. Btw, which editor are you using?

Comment: @user6969 Visual Studio Code 1.42.1